# Deciphering traceback from ARM CPU on Evaluation Board

Tags: arm, yocto, irq, petalinux

I am using a petalinux  / yocto on a evaluation board with a MpSoc and a FPGA. I am new to this whole Embedded Linux and gereeted with this error message when I try to run a precompiled example. Any pointers on what's going wrong is appreciated.

```
[   91.171070] rcu: INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
[   91.176642] rcu:     0-....: (5249 ticks this GP) idle=66a/1/0x4000000000000002 softirq=1286/1286 fqs=2625
[   91.186107]  (t=5252 jiffies g=1737 q=5)
[   91.190013] Task dump for CPU 0:
[   91.193225] resnet50        R  running task        0   740    608 0x00000002
[   91.200265] Call trace:
[   91.202701]  dump_backtrace+0x0/0x140
[   91.206352]  show_stack+0x14/0x20
[   91.209652]  sched_show_task+0xf4/0x120
[   91.213479]  dump_cpu_task+0x40/0x50
[   91.217038]  rcu_dump_cpu_stacks+0xa0/0xe0
[   91.221118]  rcu_sched_clock_irq+0x52c/0x780
[   91.225372]  update_process_times+0x2c/0x68
[   91.229539]  tick_sched_handle.isra.0+0x30/0x50
[   91.234052]  tick_sched_timer+0x48/0x98
[   91.237872]  __hrtimer_run_queues+0xec/0x1e8
[   91.242125]  hrtimer_interrupt+0x110/0x2c0
[   91.246207]  arch_timer_handler_phys+0x30/0x40
[   91.250633]  handle_percpu_devid_irq+0x80/0x140
[   91.255147]  generic_handle_irq+0x24/0x38
[   91.259140]  __handle_domain_irq+0x60/0xb8
[   91.263220]  gic_handle_irq+0x5c/0xb8
[   91.266866]  el1_irq+0xb8/0x140
[   91.269992]  misc_open+0x50/0x1a0
[   91.273291]  chrdev_open+0xc4/0x200
[   91.276763]  do_dentry_open+0x104/0x398
[   91.280581]  vfs_open+0x28/0x30
[   91.283708]  path_openat+0x4a0/0x1248
[   91.287353]  do_filp_open+0x74/0xf8
[   91.290825]  do_sys_open+0x168/0x218
[   91.294384]  __arm64_sys_openat+0x20/0x28
[   91.298381]  el0_svc_common.constprop.0+0x68/0x160
[   91.303161]  el0_svc_handler+0x6c/0x88
[   91.306893]  el0_svc+0x8/0xc
```

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/stallwarn.txt as merely printing that dump took >100 ms, maybe the bit about serial console applies to you?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it with serial and with ssh connection. In the serial connection I will get this debug information, however on serial it just says nothing. Do I need to disable the serial output or is it enough to not connect it?

Comment: Try passing `quiet` on the kernel command line. That should reduce its console output. See if anything about the problem changes. The serial line does not detect whether something is connected, if it's configured, it's chugging along.

Comment: I'll try that. I have to add it before I build it, not during startup right?

Comment: That's for startup, specify that in your bootloader, no need for rebuild.

Comment: In the posted link it says that "Booting Linux using a console connection that is too slow...." but this error happens when I try to run a compiled example not during booting, just as an information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224207/discussion-between-dratenik-and-kev1n91).